# Is this an AND gate due to the fact that if one input voltage is low, and the other is high, then the X node has two different voltages?

Tags: diodes

Am I thinking of this in the correct way? Any other explanation over how this functions as an AND gate would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: `X node has two different voltages` ... that's like saying `my coffee cup is filled to two different levels`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A node has one voltage. That's what a node is.

Given the current source, one or both of the diodes will be conducting. You can now write the input voltages for all combinations of input, and see what the output voltage is. Remember that a diode conducts only when forward biased, and if so then the forward voltage drop is about 0.7V. If a diode is *not* forward-biased, it is like an open circuit in this case.

You're correct that it is an AND gate. But you should build this thing on a breadboard or in a simulator and play with it to see what it does.

This site provides everything you'll need for that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWFobM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When you run the simulation, click on any of the logic inputs (1 in a circle), and press space to toggle it. The current and voltage meters help you see what's happening, and where do the currents flow.

Again: this site provides the schematic editor and circuit simulator for you inside of each question and answer editor box. There's a little schematic symbol that inserts a schematic. Simple enough schematics can be simulated in real time as you tweak them (at DC).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is an AND gate.  But its not due to the fact that X would have two different voltages.  X will always have exactly one voltage.

If either A or B is low then X will be low.
X will only be high if both A and B are high.

The forward voltage of D1 or D2 is going to be nominally 0.7V.  So if A is low then the other side of D1 must be at 0.7V.  0.7V would be considered logic low.  The same argument applies to B and D2.